# How to split both data based on character in cell value, and data formatted as wrapped text without the character

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a macro that splits data in cell value into multiple rows along with corresponding column data.

Example:
Cell b2 has value "G2HSB; G4ZQP".
[image: Data]

These are split into multiple rows along with corresponding column values.
[image: Macro Output]

The macro splits data based on the character **;** within cell value.

I have some values where the character **;** is not present and output is wrong, like this.
[image: some wrong output]

In the original Excel file the data is like this
[image: Original excel data without ;]

They are wrap text true by default. I want the macro to split these data also in multiple rows with corresponding column data.

My original code

```vb
Sub MsoSplit()

    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("Exclusion Data").Range("B2").End(xlDown)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ";")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exclusion Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
    Next cell

    Dim cell1 As Range
    For Each cell1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exclusion Data").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        cell1 = WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell1)
    Next cell1

    Worksheets("Exclusion Data").UsedRange.WrapText = False
 
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "In original excel file the data is like this" do you mean that what we can see in the following picture is a string in "B2" containing many lines? Do you want 'transforming' the cell content in so many rows as lines number exists? If so, where do you want the processing return to be placed? In the same column? In another sheet, or where? Then, is there (in column B:B) only one such a cell ("B2")? If not, how do you like the code to proceed?

Comment: How should "with corresponding column data" be understood?

Comment: The macro above has no error it splits data based (;) which is in column (G9NPT;H0FBD;H1ZSM;H1ZSN;H2NLX) so macro splits data by identifying separator ;  into multiple rows. However I have some data which does not have the separator ";" but that cell is wrap text true which is in image 4. I want to split those also into multiple column. When you see image 4 value i 1 below another. When I execute my macro it splits data only having ; separator the image 4 cell value comes in 1 cell altogether which is wrong. I need to split these data with 1 more condition OI need help on that.

Comment: Image 3 is wrong output only for image 4 value. Is there any possible way that I split data for image 4 where there is no separator ; but the cell has wrap text true by default

Comment: Image 2 is output of image 1 which is correct. 
Image 3 is output of image 4 which is wrong. 
Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ";")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
I need to add something with If or Or condition that which split data based on ; and the data with wrap text which is in image 4

Comment: Then, why did you destroy the rest of columns, since you try saying that they are needed?  Should I understand the question in the next way: If in  "B2" are 10 lines, should the code place them on 10 rows, but also repeat the existing content of the columns A, C, D, E ten times? Even so, I asked you if there is only "B2" cell to be treated in this way. Which to be your answer at this question?

Comment: Yes if b2 are 10 lines then code place then in 10 rows.

Comment: This was obvious, but I asked about different aspects: "If in "B2" are 10 lines, should the code place them on 10 rows, but also repeat the existing content of the columns A, C, D, E ten times? " and "I asked you if there is only "B2" cell to be treated in this way". So, is it? If not, how do you like the code to proceed in such a situation? Please, try some examples. I cannot understand to well what you try saying, no offence...

Comment: You can do this in Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365) with a single step from the UI:  `Split by delimiter into Rows`

Comment: You already received an answer and I have another one prepared, based on the above assumption. Shouldn't you confirm that it reflects what you need? Anyhow, I will also post my code. It uses only array and should be very fast...

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `;` with a space, use `Application.Trim` to removes all spaces from text except for single spaces between words, and then split on the spaces that remain.

```vb
    Dim s As String
    With Worksheets("Exclusion Data")
        Set r = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        Do While r.Row > 1
            s = Application.Trim(Replace(r.Value, ";", " "))
            ar = Split(s, " ")
            If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
            For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
                r.EntireRow.Copy
                r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
            Next
            Set r = r.Offset(-1)
        Loop
        .UsedRange.WrapText = False
    End With
```

Comment: thanks but what is ar = Split(s, " ") what is ar? is it variant, long or range

Comment: @akshay an array (variant), same as in your code `ar = Split(r.Value, ";")`

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next code. It returns in another sheet the processed result. In the actual code, in the next sheet, but you can set whichever sheet you want. The code uses arrays and should be very fast for a big range to be processed:

```
Sub splitCellValueByRows()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, sep As String
   Dim arr, arrExist, arrFin, i As Long, nrRows As Long, j As Long, k As Long, e As Long
   
   Set sh = Worksheets("Exclusion Data")
   Set shDest = sh.Next  'Use here the sheet where to return.
                         'If keep this code, next sheet must exist and it should be empty
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   
   arrExist = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value
   sep = " ;"  'used separator for Split
               'if it is not consistent (as it can be seen), it can  be
               'solved, if you confirm that no spaces involved in the separated strings
   'calculate final number of rows, in the processed array:
   For i = 2 To UBound(arrExist)
        nrRows = nrRows + UBound(Split(arrExist(i, 2), sep)) + 1
   Next i
   ReDim arrFin(1 To nrRows + 1, 1 To UBound(arrExist, 2)): k = 1
   
   'place the header in the final array:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrExist, 2)
        arrFin(k, i) = arrExist(1, i)
   Next i

   k = k + 1 'initialize the variable of final array rows
   For i = 2 To UBound(arrExist)
        arr = Split(arrExist(i, 2), sep)
         
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
            arrFin(k, 1) = arrExist(i, 1): arrFin(k, 2) = arr(j)
            For e = 3 To lastCol
                arrFin(k, e) = arrExist(i, e)
            Next
            k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next i

   shDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

If you like its return, you can replace the existing content with the array result. Just replace `shDest` with `sh` in the last code line.

Comment: your code returns the same output which my code give the output. The output of image 4 is still the same as in image 3 need assistance "arrExist = sh.Range("A1", sh.Cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value
   sep = ";"  'used separator for Split" 
if ; separator then split or if cell is wrap text without ";" as showed in image 4 it should split in multiple rows.

Comment: @Akshay Chari This only proves that I did not understand your question. Since you were not able to answer the clarification questions, like I said in my last comment,  the answer is based on my assumption. Wasting my time trying to help is not something I like. So, I wish you a good day and you maybe will learn how to ask a question. Your pictures is so chosen mostly to confuse us. At least, on my taste.